# Como bloquear que o aplicativo minimize C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Galera, eu tenho um app windows form que depois de abrir uma nova tela ela ta minimizando sozinha e eu não estou conseguindo descobrir o motivo.

Todas as telas eu chamo da seguinte forma

```
Home PagHome = new Home();
PagHome.Show();
this.Close();
```

E ao iniciar os forms, eu coloco no load o seguinte codigo

```
  this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
  this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
  this.MaximizeBox = false;
  this.MinimizeBox = false;
```

Não esta aparecendo nenhum erro, e a tela está abrindo, porem após abrir que esta minimizando.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: bom realizei diversos testes usando o Visual Studio 2017 e com esse código que você postou não verifiquei erro algum.
Porém você já verificou se não está usando `this.Close()` no formulário principal ?
Poste o resto do código do seu formulário.

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho como testar agora por estar ao celular, mas creio que possas utilizar o evento Resize do form:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) {
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
}
```